# How to POST multiple values with Selector value in html/php

Tags: php, html, post

I want to know how to POST json object fields based

```
<?php 
$jsondata = file_get_contents('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=google-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=xxxxxxx');
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$tasks = $data['articles'];
foreach ( $tasks as $task) {
     $news_title = $task['title'];
     $news_url = $task['url'];
     $news_imagUrl = $task['urlToImage'];
echo "<option value='".$task."'>".$news_title."</option>";        }
?>
```

Now, i want to post all the values like title, url, urlToImage on sumbit.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please illustrate with an example

Comment: are you trying to make a form in html?